# upload file from android to php server

Tags: php, android, codeigniter

I am trying to upload  a image from my android app to my php server.
It is working fine in server side when i am using basic php upload code like

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)
```

But when i am trying to upload in server using codeigniter it can't.. my codeigniter code is

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/companyLicDoc/';
$config['file_name']="test.jpg"; 
$config['overwrite']='TRUE';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
$config['max_size'] = '2024';
$config['max_width'] = '2024';
$config['max_height'] = '1768';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->do_upload("uploaded_file");
```

help me please..

Comment: whats the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this line:

```
echo $this->upload->display_errors();
```

this will show you the error message behind the failing upload process which it might be:

- httpd doesn't have access to the upload folder or it doesn't exist.
- the file upload parameter name specified in the Android app is not the same in the codeigniter `"uploaded_file"`.

Comment: file upload parameter name in the Android app is same as "uploaded_file"... i think it is a problem in codeigniter code.. becz my basic php upload code works fine

Comment: have you used the `display_errors()` method ? what is the result ?